# How to switch from database in postgres with psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I try to switch with powershell from databases with postgres (14.1)

So I do this:

```
postgres-# \l
```

And then I see all the databases. But for example how can I now switch to the test database?

```
  Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |         Collate          |          Ctype           |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_Netherlands.1252 | English_Netherlands.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_Netherlands.1252 | English_Netherlands.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                          |                          | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_Netherlands.1252 | English_Netherlands.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                          |                          | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test      | postgres | UTF8     | English_Netherlands.1252 | English_Netherlands.1252 |
(4 rows)
```

I try it like this:

```
postgres-# -d --test
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\connect` (or just `\c`)

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

> `\c` or `\connect`
>
> Establishes a new connection to a PostgreSQL server. The connection parameters to use can be specified either using a positional syntax (one or more of database name, user, host, and port), or using a conninfo connection string as detailed in Section 34.1.1. If no arguments are given, a new connection is made using the same parameters as before.

The `-d` parameter can only be used when starting `psql`:

```
PS c:\> psql -d test
```

Comment: ahhh, oke. Thank you!! oke